# unpacking values outside a class error

Tags: python, class, csv

I am trying to read in a csv file data and store the data using a class. My variables are not defined in the file directly, but as an input from the csv file. I  want to read the Line `Ground`as an input for the class `Building_Storey` and split the line using the class method  `from_st`.However I receive this error `too many values to unpack (expected 4)` and the error message `missing 3 required positional arguments` if I split the line `Ground` earlier in the code.it seems that he reads the whole line as one string, and gives the first argument to the whole line. I don't know what is the problem with this code.

Input csv file:

```
TABLE;BuildingStorey;
GbxmlID;Name;Level;Internal Height;
F0;GroundFloor;0;3.7
F1;FirstFloor;4;3.7
F2;SecondFloor;16;8
```

The code :

```
with open('file.csv', 'r')as fp:
    copy = fp.readlines()
    print(copy)
    l = 0
    for line in copy:
        l = l + 1
        if l == 3:
            if 'GroundFloor' in line:
                Ground = line
                print(Ground) 

class Building_Storey:
    def __init__(self, GbxmlID, Name, Level, Internal_Height):

        self.GbxmlID = GbxmlID
        self.Name = Name
        self.Level = Level
        self.Internal_Height = Internal_Height

    @classmethod
    def from_st(cls, Story_st):
        GbxmlID, Name, Level, Internal_Height = Story_st.split(';')
        return cls(GbxmlID, Name, Level, Internal_Height)

Groundfloor = Building_Storey.from_st(Ground)  
print(Groundfloor.GbxmlID)
print(Groundfloor.Name)
print(Groundfloor.Level)
print(Groundfloor.Internal_Height)
```

Output should be:

```
  F0;GroundFloor;0;3.7;;;;;;;  # the line I want to read
  GroundFloor.GbxmlID = F0
  GroundFloor.Name = GroundFloor
  GroundFloor.Level = 0
  GroundFloor.Internal_Height = 3.7
```

Comment: `Story_st` is a `str`, not a function that can be called with a `;` as an argument. You want `Story_st.split(';')`.

Comment: @chepner it was a typing error, thanks. But I still have a problem with the splitting..this error also appear: too many values to unpack (expected 4) do you have any idea why?

Comment: `TABLE;BuildingStorey;` only splits into 3 fields (the third being empty); what would `Internal_Height` be assigned in that case?

Comment: Or `GbxmlID;Name;Level;Internal Height;` will be split into 5 fields; what would the 5th (empty) field be assigned to?

Comment: @chepner, thats why I need to read in line by line as the line differes, in the case of the line F0;GroundFloor;0;3.7 I should have four fields. I was thinking to define a new class  read another line with 5 fields. The problem I am facing is that he even after splitting, he reads the list as one field for ex. he assigns the GbxmlID in the class to this list ['F0', 'GroundFloor', '0', '3.7'], but he can't assign Name, Level to what is equivalent. I hope this is clear

Comment: They you need to check the length of the tuple returned by `split` before you attempt to unpack it. `fields = Story_st.split(';'); if len(fields) == 4: w, x, y, z = fields`.

Comment: @chepner. I have checked the length of the line: `if 'GroundFloor' in line:
                Ground = line
                items_0 = Ground.split(';')
                print(len(items_0))`it gives a length of 11. however, when I assign `the Items_1 = items_0[:4]`to be sure that I have a list of four fields, I get the error `missing 3 required positional arguments`

Answer (score 0):

You could skip the first two "header" lines and then read each line in using Python's `csv` library to automatically split the text into a list of values per row. If the list contains `4` entries, pass the values directly to your class using `*` to pass each list element as an argument to your class:

```
import csv

class Building_Storey:
    def __init__(self, GbxmlID, Name, Level, Internal_Height):
        self.GbxmlID = GbxmlID
        self.Name = Name
        self.Level = Level
        self.Internal_Height = Internal_Height

with open('file.csv', newline='') as f_file:    
    csv_file = csv.reader(f_file, delimiter=';')
    header_1 = next(csv_file)
    header_2 = next(csv_file)

    for row in csv_file:
        if len(row) == 4:
            floor = Building_Storey(*row)
            print("ID: {}, Name: {}, Level: {}, Height: {}".format(floor.GbxmlID, floor.Name, floor.Level, floor.Internal_Height))
```

This would display:

```
ID: F0, Name: GroundFloor, Level: 0, Height: 3.7
ID: F1, Name: FirstFloor, Level: 4, Height: 3.7
ID: F2, Name: SecondFloor, Level: 16, Height: 8
```